# SXC 9 Update 2 Installation error "Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.Collection.Model.dll: Access to the path denied"

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-install-framework

While installing Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0 Update 2 I see an error as

> Remove-Item : Cannot remove item
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sxp9u2.xconnect\App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.Collection.Model.dll:
>   Access to the path
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sxp9u2.xconnect\App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.Collection.Model.dll'
>   is denied. At
>   C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:1006
>   char:29
>   + ...             Remove-Item -LiteralPath $currentArchiveEntryFileInfo.Ful ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\inetpub\wwwr...ction.Model.dll:FileInfo) [Remove-Item],
>   UnauthorizedAccessException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

[image]

I even tried deleting the dll manually to see the issue as below
[image]

Comment: Can you stop the Windows Service Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine sxp9u2...? Removed tasks that finished already from deployment folder\SIF\Configuration\Commerce\Master_SingleServer.json file under Tasks and run the ps1 again

Comment: Thanks this helped and I was able to run through the InstallAutomationEngineModule but I am getting an error after this step as https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/sxc-9-update-2-installation-error-sitecore-commerce-engine-connect-2-2-86-updat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to complete the InstallAutomationEngineModule stop the " Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine sxp9u2" service and re-run the Installation.
[image]

Make sure you edit the Master_SingleServer.json(Deploy folder\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.2.14\Configuration\Commerce) to start with the step "InstallCommerceMAModule" and remove all the previous steps. 
This will save time and help you to concentrate on specific error rather than going for all the succeeded steps again from the beginning.