# SXC 9 Update 2 Installation error: Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.2.2.86.update Package installation failed

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-install-framework

While installing Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0 Update 2 I got the error where Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.2.2.86.update package installation failed and I get the below error:

[image]

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ InstallPackage : InstallPackage -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Installing package:  Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.2.2.86.update
    http://sxa.storefront.com/SiteUtilityPages/InstallPackages.aspx?package=Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.2.2.86.update
    Install-SitecoreConfiguration :

            One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'packageinstall:items:ended' event.


             body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}
             p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
             b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
             H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
             H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
             pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
             .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
             .version {color: gray;}
             .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
             .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
             @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
              pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
             }
             @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
              pre { width: 280px; }
             }



                Server Error in '/' Application.
                 One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'packageinstall:items:ended' event.

                 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

                 Exception Details: System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'packageinstall:items:ended' event.
                Source Error:




    Line 56:             try
    Line 57:             {
    Line 58:                 entries = UpdateHelper.Install(installationInfo, log, out text);
    Line 59:                 MetadataView view = UpdateHelper.LoadMetadata(installationInfo.Path);
    Line 60:                 var installer = new DiffInstaller(installationInfo.Action);


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQt9S.png
```

I even tried analysing the Package with Install Update Package from Sitecore and found the below error:

```
Error installing 'addeditems/master/sitecore/templates/commerce/catalog/commerce catalog/__standard values_{81c273b0-8f34-4371-aa9f-d76bfae6d9ff}'. More info
Some of the installation operation cannot be performed.
An exception occured when trying to install 'addeditems/master/sitecore/templates/commerce/catalog/commerce catalog/__standard values_{81c273b0-8f34-4371-aa9f-d76bfae6d9ff}'.
Details: Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException: Status Code: 401; Unauthorized at Microsoft.OData.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult) at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy.Proxy.GetValue[T](DataServiceQuerySingle`1 query) at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.CatalogRepository.GetLanguages() at
```

Comment: Do anyone have any fix for this? I tried this but the issue is still existing https://naveed-ahmad.com/2018/02/25/sitecore-experience-commerce-xc9-troubleshooting-your-installation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it update the connection string SQL Server instance name manually to

```
Server:”MACHINE\\SQLEXPRESS2016″
```

in the following configuration JSON files and in some files you have to do it at 2 places:

\SitecoreIdentityServer\wwwroot\appsettings.json    \CommerceShops_Sc9\wwwroot\bootstrap\Global.json    \CommerceOps_Sc9\wwwroot\bootstrap\Global.json    \CommerceMinions_Sc9\wwwroot\bootstrap\Global.json    \CommerceAuthoring_Sc9\wwwroot\bootstrap\Global.json    \CommerceShops_Sc9\wwwroot\data\Environments\Plugin.SQL.PolicySet-1.0.0.json    \CommerceShops_Sc9\wwwroot\data\Environments\PlugIn.Habitat.CommerceAuthoring-1.0.0.json    \CommerceShops_Sc9\wwwroot\data\Environments\PlugIn.AdventureWorks.CommerceAuthoring-1.0.0.json

Once you have made these changes, please do an iisreset before running the script again from PowerShell.

Reference: https://naveed-ahmad.com/2018/02/25/sitecore-experience-commerce-xc9-troubleshooting-your-installation/